# keyboard shortcut to jump cursor to prompt?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

I often mistype a command. So I will type this

```
sublimetext myfile.txt
```

instead of

```
git add myfile.txt
```

When I do this, I hit up to restore the last command. But after doing so, my cursor is at the end of the previously typed line. Is there a keyboard short cut to jump back to the prompt?

Comment: You can also just type `git add`, then press `Esc`,`.` - it will type `myfile.txt` (the last argument of previous command) automatically.

Comment: @Vi. Thanks. It is a bit hard to read your comment. I should type "git add" then press the esc key, then press the comma key, then press period key?

Comment: Escape key, then period key. Without comma. There's more Esc-Something shortcuts actually. You can also use Alt+Period. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211378/hidden-features-of-bash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On bash command line, I use `ctrl+a` to go to the beginning of command and `ctrl+e` to go to the end of command.

Answer (score 4):

After you press <kbd>Up</kbd> to recall the previous line, press <kbd>Home</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Gilles, you just spoiled my kinda-troll attempt.